# Issue with apostrophes and/or single quotes

Tags: replace, textarea, apostrophe

I'm working with ImageMagick and the paragraph being displayed stops where an apostrophe occurs.  The strange thing is that the ´ works but the ' doesn't.  (sorry but I'm not sure of the technical term for the ´ apostrophe.

I started noticing inconsistent behavior when I realized that not all users are typing straight into the textarea box.  They are also pasting from a Word file.

I tried addslashes because I read that in order to show a word with apostrophe you have to escape it first but that didn't work.

The only thing I can come up with is if someone knows how to do a replace from ' to ´ and I can just convert it that way.

I believe they may be called "smart apostrophes" vs. "straight apostrophes".  I wish there was another way but so far the "smart" version seems to be the only way Imagemagick will display text.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are not using a wysiwyg (What you see is what you get), you'll always have problem with character from Microsoft application as Word.

There are two solutions I guess.

1) Download a wysiwyg (ckeditor or tyniMCE)

2) When a user submit the textarea convert using this :

```
function clean_msword_string($string) {

  $search = array(chr(145), 
               chr(146), 
               chr(147), 
               chr(148), 
               chr(151),
               chr(156)); 

  $replace = array("'", 
                "'", 
                '"', 
                '"', 
                '-',
                'œ'); 

return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 

}
```